# Page numbers are missing

Tags: header-footer

As are as I understand, page numbering is automatic  but I am not getting page numbers.  The start of my document is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\title{Something}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{url}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@fancy 
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\chapter{Introduction}
```

How do I get the page numbering started at the first page of the \chapter?

Comment: The `\maketitle` typically issues `\pagestyle{empty}`. Where exactly do you want the page numbering to start? From the first page of your `\chapter`?

Comment: You're emptying all fields for the header and footer, so nothing will be printed.

Comment: At the first page of the \chapter in answer to Werner's comment. I have edited the question text to clarify this.

Comment: Werner's reply stands. You're giving no hint about where the page number should be printed.

Comment: The page that starts Chapter 1 should be where the page numbering starts. I am not fussed where on the page, but say the middle of the bottom footer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Makes no real sense, but is possible:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\title{Something}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@fancy 
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\let\ps@empty\ps@plain
\maketitle
\endgroup
\chapter{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If I understand this answer correctly, I just replace ```\maketitle``` with the ```begingroup``` block. I have tried this, and still no page numbers. I also do not understand what you mean by `makes no sense`

Comment: You also need the `\cfoot{\thepage}` otherwise no page has a number. On a titlepage is by default no page number.